# Laravel 5.2 eloquent returns soft deleted records

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using `Laravel 5.2`.

I have a `model` as below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class ZoomMeeting extends BaseModel {

    public $timestamps=true;        

    protected $table = 'zoom_meetings';

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'uuid', 'meeting_id', 'host_id', 'topic', 'status', 'type', 'start_url', 'join_url', 'created_at'];

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

And the base model is as below:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class BaseModel extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected static function boot()
     {
            //parent::boot();

            static::creating(function($model) {
                if(empty($model->created_at))
                {
                    $model->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                }
                return true;
            });

            static::updating(function($model) {
            $model->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            return true;
            });
     } 
}
```

I am using `softdeletetrait` in `ZoomMeeting` model, and soft deleting is working fine.

However, if I fetch records from the same model using eloquent, it returns the soft deleted records too. I am using code below to get the records:

```
$record = ZoomMeeting::where("user_id", $user_id)->where("meeting_id", $meeting_id)->orderBy("id", "DESC")->first();
```

The `eloquent` is building the `query` as:

```
select * from `zoom_meetings` where `user_id` = 3 and `meeting_id` = 707070707 order by `id` desc limit 1
```

See, there is no `deleted at is null` set in `where` statement. It is not preventing the deleted records.

I am not sure where am I making mistake?

Comment: Any experts available here??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are overriding the `boot` method, but you aren't ever actually calling the parent `boot` method (it's commented out), so the trait is never getting initialized correctly.  I believe that also means the data you have been deleting is actually being deleted from the database.

Is there a reason you need to override the boot method?  What you are adding is already done handled by the framework, so it doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just have removed comment from parent::boot() in base class and it seems working fine now.